# Fiddler Not decrypting Https traffic from any browser on Windows

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I have installed V4.4.9.3 of fiddler and trying to capture the HTTPS traffic but invain. I am keep on getting the following logs in Event logs tab

!SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized on pipe to(CN=, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)
Can any body suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed the fiddler root certificate install steps as indicated here

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert

Comment: Yes sudheer I have performed those steps

Comment: Try this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/httpfiddler/bugs-problems-and-troubleshooting/3vguECC-DOw . Try those forums instead  of here.